# unable to connect new server in Microsoft Sql 2005

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005

hi i am using Microsoft SQL 2005 ... i am currently using it with one active server ... but i am not able to create new server in it .. as shown in image [please view error print screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vINP.png)

Error

===================================

Testing the registered server failed. Verify the server name, login credentials, and database, and then click Test again.

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

---

Error Number: -1
Severity: 20
State: 0

My old server is working fine but i am not able to connect new server ...

Comment: Trying using the pipe address or the IP. Also, did you install a new instance or are you just trying to add one in management studio? You can't do that.

Comment: Is it another instance of SQL Server? Like for example your older server is a sepárate instalation, or three are two instantes in The same version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Check The network status on configuration manager under protocols and enable all three... And try, or check on The firewall if it allows The exception for sqlsrv and sqlbrowser... The server connection is local or remote from another Pc?

Comment: thank you for your reply 
 server connection is local ...
my one server is running fine
but when i create new server it shows the error in image .. still i will check the things you mention

Answer (score 0):

If there are two servers on The same computer your problem is The ports, The older server is using port 1433, and The new one too, so that is The problem, to solvet go to firewall advanced configuration, and create a rule for a tcp protocols and choose another port for The new server like Say 12000, for example, and Then go to browser on configuration manager at services and in all The tcp ports write The new one and problem solved, hete in My contry is late tomorrow I will post some screen shots for help...

Comment: i understand what you are saying that creating new port for my server i am not aware how to do this .. let me google it and try out

Answer (score 0):

Tell me how did it went in the search for the answer???
 I will post the answer now...

- First go to Firewall
- Clic on advance configuration
- Clic on entrance rules
- Clic on add rule
  Then follow the images shown here for creating a new rule

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: I connot upload more than 2 links for the reputation I need to have 10 point to upload the rest... have patience... I could have post the hole answer but Jamal take one point from me so please have patience... I will upload the other images later...

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the images...

[image: Type the number off the port...]
[image: Allow all connections...]
[image: Save the rule, asing a name and a descriptio]

> After creating the rule you go to SQL SERVER Configuration Manager (The red >lunchbox icon) and follow the istructions on the pictures....

[image: Clic under Network]
[image: Clic on second tab by the name Ip Adresses]
[image: Type the number of the port that you created in the Firewall Rule]

> Remember to chage the value on 8 fileds in the form that sohws the last >picture, then I think youre problem is solved!!!
>
> By the way my name is Jorge Torselli...